# how to change a variable's name to another variable's value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way I can generate variable names in python in a loop and assign values to them
? For example, if I have

I have list as

```
     [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.03675300'},
     {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00838900'},
     {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'price': '0.00152680'},........]
```

i want variable values as

```
     ETHBTC.price = 0.03675300
     LTCBTC.price = 0.00838900
     BNBBTC.price = 0.00152680


     and soo on....
```

I have tried this

but how can I change the x1 name to etc_btc.value

```
for x in range(431):
    y = prices[x]
    eth_btc = Namespace(**y)
    eth_btc.price = float(eth_btc.price)
    print(eth_btc.price,eth_btc.symbol)
    x1 = eth_btc.symbol
    x1 = eth_btc.price
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the problem, but it sounds like you just need to use a dictionary with the symbols as the key, and the price as the value. Then you'd just do `price_dict = {}; price_dict['ETHBTC'] = '0.03675300'`. Dynamically creating variables makes your code confusing to understand, and should be avoided.

Comment: create a class , having price as object . assign the  symbol value to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, It is not a good idea to dynamically create variable names. An alternative solution would be to create the following prices dictionary:

```
li = [
        {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.03675300'},
        {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00838900'},
        {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'price': '0.00152680'},
    ]

prices = {}

for entry in li:
    prices.update({entry['symbol']:entry['price']})

print(prices)
```

Returns:

`{'ETHBTC': '0.03675300', 'LTCBTC': '0.00838900', 'BNBBTC': '0.00152680'}`

I found your answer with the help of this SO question: [SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression while creating a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810927/syntaxerror-keyword-cant-be-an-expression-while-creating-a-dictionary)